# How to share code style between Xcode and AppCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, coding-style, appcode

We want to start to use AppCode in my team but we want to use same code style between Xcode and AppCode (we're already using Uncrustify on Xcode).

Does someone have experience sharing code styles between Xcode and AppCode? Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was exact my problem one year ago.

There is [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-9284) for `AppCode` to allow `uncrustify` import.

I ended up with solution that took me one day. Unfortunately `uncrustify` doesn't have documentation. As well categorisation of formatting in `uncrustify` is different from `AppCode`. I made `uncrustify` config as close as possible for `AppCode` formatting settings. I didn't succeed 100% but amount of difference is quite small (and still annoying). All configs ended up on wiki and in [repository](https://github.com/minddistrict/ios-formatting).

Finally all in our team (me and my buddy) are using AppCode and quite rare open Xcode. That was main fix for formatting.